# iOS UI elements porting on Android

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, porting

ladies and gentlemen!

Very often on my job I meet the following requirement from the client, when developing android applications: "make it look like and iPhone app".

Yes, I know, that the best way is to offer him canonical Android design with all these patterns like dashboard, using menu button etc... But sometimes this is not the case, as instead, I have to make it look and animate just the same. It's frustrating.

Can you guys, please advice me an android library (if there is one) with iOS-like UI elements? Many thanks in advance, I'm looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: Upvote for opening line

Comment: IMO iOS UI elements are boring and dated now. They've been around for far too long and the UI is looking boring and in need of a refresh. I think a well designed Android app with action bar and dashboard looks much better. Doesn't help you, I know... but that's why its a comment I guess.

Comment: Yea, right. I'd love to develop some "native" design app, but this is often not the case, when developing service apps, and not product ones

Comment: I think there's a case to be said here for educating yourself and your clients.  Android users don't want an iPhone interface and it doesn't make the best use of the hardware.  Educate your client to the differences and benefits of tailoring the interface, and educate yourself as to how best make this argument.

Comment: thank you, but that's pretty obvious, eventhough as I said before, this is not the case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To expand on **Martyn's** comment, which I agree with.

Perhaps there is a great reason why a client would ask for this, but in many cases I bet they might benefit from being challenged on this requirement.  If I was presented with this request, I would first ask "Why?".  Perhaps they'd answer as follows:

1. we need a consistent experience across platforms, or
2. it will be more cost effective to design once and apply to each platform, or
3. it doesn't matter why, just do it!

Here are some responses for each:

1. each user will generally have one phone, and won't require the experience on Android to be identical to iPhone - they only care that it works and looks great on their phone.  In fact, an Android user would prefer if you used the UI patterns that are more common to the platform, as opposed designing to match iOS.   Likewise for an iPhone user.
2. we have found that having a designer create a set of creative for iOS allows us to pretty much use the creative as-is for Android.  Even though Android might have Tabs on top, versus bottom, we are still able to take the backgrounds, button styles, fonts and color schemes from one platform to the next.  There will be slight differences, but overall the brand and look should translate well.  Here is an example of porting a single creative design across platforms: http://daleburgosdesign.com/
3. if they answer in this manner, you might want to consider passing on the job.  Pixel perfect matching across platforms is tricky aside from the ideas offered in previous answers (OpenGL and the use of a WebView - via Macarse).  If the client can't provide good reasoning for this tricky requirement, then it might be best to search for your next client.

Not a straight forward answer to your question, but I hope you find it helpful!

Answer (score 5):

There is no iphone UI library for android that I know of. What you can do is, get the iphone GUI psd and redo it for 3 sizes of android (for the 3 size ranges) and use the elements of these psd's to theme your application.

I get these kind of similar requirements. Sometimes it wont be much about the looks but about the navigation flow of the application and how new views or activities are animated. From my experience, there is no easy way to do it. So I end up making a lot of adjustments and hacks to get the job done. And I over bill the client. :)

Btw you could also consider libraries such as Sencha Touch, it will look the same in all phones that use a webkit browser.

Comment: there's four size ranges - ldpi mdpi hdpi xhdpi

Comment: Thank you for that great advice. Can you tell me more about Sencha Touch? What about it's performance? It's Javascript, so that's a reasonable question I think ^_^

Comment: Sencha Touch is a javascript library which supports all mobile devices with a webkit browser. They already have built it widget for all common controls in iOS. They recently added charts to their library. I have worked with it once for a project and my experience was pretty good with it. You can wrap the whole thing phone gap which allows you to access to native api such as camera's. If you check out the showcase inside the forum you can see different apps. Its performance is pretty descent for javascript. I wont say that it  has a native app speed but its pretty good for a web app.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there are no 'iOS-alike' widget libraries for Android.

Because of this, you could reasonably charge the client more for both development and support, thereby providing an incentive to stick with the standard Android UI design and principles.

Answer (score 1):

There is no library to port iphone views to Android but if you are starting both applications from the scratch you have two possible approach to share views between both platforms.

First one is using `WebView`s and coding `HTML`, `JS` and `CSS`. This kind of app is called hybrid.

Second one is using openGL. You can do it directly or using a framework like [cocos2d-x](http://cocos2d-x.org/).

Depending on what you are willing to you should choose what to use.