# Android layout designing

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android development. Can you give me some tips on creating UI layout as shown on the image below? Thanks for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this layout design

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:background="#092EA1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/login"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/user_name" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:id="@+id/textUserName"
                android:hint="@string/username" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/password"  />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:id="@+id/textPassword"
                android:inputType="textWebPassword" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:src="@drawable/button_login" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgotPass"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_login"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
                android:text="@string/forgotText"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/error_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textPassword"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/forgotPass"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                android:textColor="#f51313"
                android:text="" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Set the postion as you want to get

Answer (score 0):

Come on, google around a bit before just asking questions like this.

Read these two answers (btw, found by typing "android iphone-like ui elements" in Google search):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11647020/375929
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7212532/375929

They've got all you need, including the explanations on why *it's a very bad idea to make Android apps look like iOS*.

Brief summary: it's because the users of the app will hate both you as a developer and your employer/owner_of_the_app so much both of you'll be having hiccups 24/7.

And, to top that off, your app will get bad ratings and sink to the bottom of the Play Store, which is **very** hard to recover from --- you know, if you get 1 star in any of the reviews, you're never getting 5.0 average unless the user changers their mind and rating - and they won't, because they'll never take another look at it once they see iOS-derived UI. Also, goes without saying, no Android app with UI directly ported from iOS will *ever* get featured.

So please, if you're in a position where you can suggest the app owner to just use native  Android controls or, better yet, redesign the app to conform to the [Android UI Design guide](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html), **please do convince them to do so and be proud for boldly taking your part in fighting the global diabolic evil**.

*PS I know you're probably not the one calling shots about the app --- otherwise you wouldn't be porting iOS UI to Android. It's a typical contractor thing to do that, I've had my share of it.*

*PPS* Here's a very good lean explanation of the *don't-copy-design-of-other-platforms* approach to usability by Google: [Pure Android](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html)